# Why is Rust `cargo build` output corrupted in SecureCRT?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, terminal-emulator, secure-crt

When I run `cargo build` it prints non-printable characters, which lock the terminal.  I can workaround it, but I wonder why a tool would do that and how do I prevent it?

For example:

```
$ cargo build
   Compiling crypto-speed v0.1.0 (/home/dano/rust/speed)
error[E0277]: `std::time::Duration` doesn't implement `std::fmt::Display`
  퍊     ۽۰۰퍊     ۽۰      ۽۰                                              퍊     ۽۰۰퍊     ۽۰庺퍊     ۽۰  ۰퍊     ۽۰  ۽   ۽۰۰퍊     ۽   ۽۰   퍊     ۽ 宍
                                                                         ۰
```

I run SecureCRT, which is similar to PuTTY and other terminal programs. `ls --color=always` works, as does all the other color output. Just `rustc` is broken.

Comment: Probably your terminal is shit. Which are you using?

Comment: I was using TERM=ansi through a ssh client, SecureCRT.
I changed it to something simple (without color), TERM=vt100 and it works OK.

Comment: Terminal setting issues are (usually) nigh-impossible to reproduce and (usually) have little to do with the program you're running, but have something to do with your environment. What about `ls --color=always`? What terminal program are you running in (Konsole, xterm, PuTTY...)?

Comment: My mistake, I didn't realize that your SSH client was also a terminal emulator. I would suggest asking on some forum or documentation specific to SecureCRT because it likely has something to do with the terminal emulation mode.

Comment: I run SecureCRT, which is similar to PuTTY and other terminal programs.  `ls --color=always` works, as does all the other color output.  Just `rustc` is broken. Of course, maybe `rustc` uses something the other color output programs do not use.

The workaround, for the benefit of others, is to pipe the stderr output to `cat -v` so `rustc` cannot corrupt the terminal.  For example, `cargo build 2>&1 | cat -v`

Comment: Maybe TERM is set wrong… try setting it to xterm?